# Own Exception Class with Toast Nofitfication

Tags: android

Hy!

I want to make my own Exception Class, but my problem is that i don'T know how to access the Context to show a Toast for the user.

My Code:

```
public class NFFException extends Exception{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public NFFException(String msg) {

    Toast.makeText(???, msg, 300);
}

}
```

Comment: You can use constructor to assign context or simply public NFFException(Context context,String msg) pass context of that activity from which this toast need to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since context is not static, so you can not use it in Exception class. One thing you can do, in any activity class, make a static field

static Context context;

initialize it in onCreate() method,

and then use this context variable in your above code

Comment: Be careful with this, as it will leak the activity on screen rotation. See this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html and this: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html